# TargetFramework resolution for implicitly referenced NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget

Assume the following situation:

- NuGet package A is built for TargetFramework netstandard 2.0.
- NuGet package A has a dependency on NuGet package B
- NuGet package B multi-targets both netstandard 2.0 and .Net7.
- Now say my own project targets .Net7, and adds a PackageReference to NuGet package A

Will my project pull in the netstandard 2.0 build, or the .Net7 build of implicitly referenced package B?

Comment: Perhaps you can find your answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution

Comment: Final transitive dependency resolution happens only for an application (not a library) - i.e. a runnable/deployable project type, and it uses the *target* framework. Assuming your project is an application: you should get the net7 build, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project is restored independently, and each package is considered in the context of the current project. So, the TFMs that a package contains has no influence on asset selection in its dependencies. Therefore, if PackageB's best/closest TFM to your app is the net7.0 binaries, that's what it's going to use. It doesn't matter what PackageA supports or was originally compiled against.

### check via msbuild debugging

I wish this wasn't the case, as I'm really not a fan of .NET's build system, but anyone doing anything non-trivial in .NET will benefit a lot from learning MSBuild basics. The best way, by far, to debug MSBuild is to add `-bl` to any command, such as `dotnet build -bl`. This will create a file called `msbuild.binlog` in the current directory, which you can then open with https://msbuildlog.com (there's a Windows app that can be downloaded, or you can use the web app). Then search the dll name, and see the source path. I don't wish becoming the entire team's go-to person for all MSBuild questions on anybody, but if you can get intermediate MSBuild skills, then you unlock a huge potential to be able to solve a lot of build related problems. It's a very useful skill for an experienced .NET developer to have.

### check via assets file

This is also quick and easy to verify. NuGet creates a file, `obj/project.assets.json` which contains all the selected assets. You can find PackageA, and look if it has `compile: [ "lib/net7.0/packageA.dll" ]` , or `lib/netstanard2.0/packageA.dll`

### check via test app

Even if you didn't know of NuGet's `project.assets.json`, it's still quick and easy to verify using test projects:

```bash
# create projects
dotnet new classlib -n ClassLib1 -f netstandard2.0
dotnet new classlib -n ClassLib2 -f netstandard2.0
dotnet new console -n App

# set up project references
dotnet add ClassLib1 reference ClassLib2
dotnet add App reference ClassLib1
```

Then, edit `ClassLib2/ClassLib2.csproj`, and change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>`

Next, edit `ClassLib2\ClassLibrary1.cs` to have a public static method (I'm showing just the method, keep the namespace and class definitions):

```cs
public static string GetFinalMessage() =>
#if NETSTANDARD
    "Hello .NET Standard";
#else
    "Hello .NET";
#endif
```

Step 3 is edit `ClassLib1\ClassLibrary1.cs` to have method `public static string GetMessage() => ClassLib2.GetFinalMessage();` (again, keep the namespace & class, I'm just showing the method).

The last edit is to `App\Program.cs`, change it to `Console.WriteLine(ClassLib1.GetMessage());`

Finally, you can run it with `dotnet run --project App`. The app will write to the console which TFM it used. You can even enhance `ClassLib2` to remove the `#if` conditional compilation, and instead use reflection to get the assembly's TargetFramework assembly attribute. But I can't write (mostly) correct code from memory for that. `typeof(ClassLibrary1).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes()` is a starting point.